# php: why declare an array $array=array() - what is the benefit of it?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

If you simply want to assign values to a variable this way:
`$array[]="value 1"` and `$array[]="value 2"`
do you first have to declare `$array=array()`? Obviously you don't HAVE to, as it works without it, but why would you do that then? Or what is the benefit of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is not a declaration but an initialization. You are not declaring $array is an array, you are assigning it a value (empty array).

Such an initialization can be used to establish a scope, and perhaps it can make the code more readable (although I can't see how), but usually it is only done when you specifically want an empty array. The classic example is when using the [] syntax to append to an array. Consider the following:

```
$a = 'old value';
$a = array();
$a[] = 1;
$a[] = 2;
$a[] = 3;
```

Without the second line, this will produce an error.

By the way, The array() command isn't an ordinary function. It's a language construct, and starting with PHP 5.4 you can replace it with the shorter [] syntax:

```
$a = 'old value';
$a = [];
$a[] = 1;
$a[] = 2;
$a[] = 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

Mostly readability I think.  Someone might (or yourself 5 months later) come along and wonder where $array[] comes from, as it "magically appears in code".   With $myArray=array(), you at least know (hey, this is where we first see the variable).

Answer (score 1):

It could also be useful when you structure your code. For example If we first declare the variable in the top

```
<?php
$myArray = array();

//...
```

And in the bottom we load a template file `$template->render('template.html', $myArray);`

Let's say we have a if statement and if the certain condition is true we assign a new value to the array. But if the condition was not true we would not pass any information (new value to the array) thus the array would not be initiated - it would generate an error unless the array wasn't declared. But since it is, we would simply just load an empty array and there would be no errors.

Comment: thanks, good point! although if using any function on this array, like `end($array)` or whatever, even if the array is declared but empty, it would result in an error... so you would have to check for that in any case, no?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly for documentative purposes. It reminds the developer that the variable is intended to be used as an array.

As an example, in CodeIgniter, you can pass values to a view, but they must be an array or it throws an exception. Declaring the variable as `array()` reminds you that even if you intend to pass a single value, you must insert it as an element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't.

Generally, the only time I initialize an array with an empty array is in cases like this:

```
$list = array();
for($database_result as $row)
{
    $list[] = $row['value'];
}

echo implode(', ', $list);
```

If it happened to be no rows in the database result, then the `implode` call would fail, since $list would not exist.

---

The example you give, of just setting a list of values you already know, I generally do like this:

```
$array = array
(
    "value 1",
    "value 2",
);
```